# It is not possible to merge the table and get values from the bridge table along the chain in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

```
class DeliveryPrice extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'delivery_prices';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'unit',
        'price',
        'is_unit_weight',
        'delivery_type_id',
        'product_category_id'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'delivery_type_id',
        'product_category_id'
    ];
}
```

```
class DeliveryType extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'delivery_types';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'min_days',
        'max_days',
    ];

    public function productCategories(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProductCategory::class, 'delivery_prices');
    }
}
```

```
class ProductCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'product_categories';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'is_active'
    ];

    public function deliveryPrices(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DeliveryPrice::class);
    }

    public function deliveryTypes(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DeliveryType::class, 'delivery_prices');
    }
}
```

In the end it should look like this using a line like this:

```
DeliveryType::with('productCategories.deliveryPrices')->get()
```

The answer should look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "DType1",
        "min_days": 10,
        "max_days": 12,
        "productCategories": [{
            "name": "PCategory1",
            "is_active": 1,
            "deliveryPrices": [{
                "unit": 0.0,
                "price": 530.0,
                "is_unit_weight": 0
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

It seems like a very simple task, but I don’t have a lot of experience in laravel and I can’t find a simple solution. Can you tell me how it is possible to implement this?

I tried to add distinct, but because of this, deliveryPrice returned the values of all DeliveryTypes, and not those at the beginning of the chain

Comment: What does `DeliveryType::with('productCategories.deliveryPrices')->get()` now produce?